# How do I set Google Cloud SQL - PostgreSQL timezone to UTC

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I see Cloud SQL - MySQL has a Database Flag to set the default_time_zone. I cannot however, find how to do the same for Cloud SQL - PostgreSQL.  I need my time zone to be UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flags that you see in `Cloud SQL - MySQL` in [Configuring Database Flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags) documentation are provided by `MySQL`. If you click on the flag `default_time_zone` that you are referring to, then you will see that you will be redirected to MySQL documentation page. For the `Cloud SQL - PostgreSQL` the flags that you see in the [Configuring Database Flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#list-flags-postgres) documentation, are provided by `PostgreSQL`, therefore they don't expose this flag or any similar flag like this.

To change the timezone of the `PostgreSQL` instance, you have to SSH into it and do it by executing query:

1. Go to the `SQL` page on the console and find your `PostgreSQL` instance.
2. On the instance's details record you will find three dots at the end. Click and select the option `Connect VM`. On the right side of your window you will see a tutorial.
3. Follow the tutorial steps to set up a `Compute Engine VM Instance` that will be connecting to your `PostgreSQL`.
4. After you finish all the steps form the tutorial. Go to the `Compute Engine` page and SSH to the instance that you created for connecting to the `PostgreSQL`.
5. Execute the `psql "sslmode=disable dbname=postgres user=postgres hostaddr=[POSTGRESQL_PUBLIC_IP]"` to connect to the instance.
6. Execute the `SELECT NOW();` to see the current timezone, that your `PostgreSQL` is running at.
7. Execute the `SET timezone to 'UTC';` to set the timezone of the `PostgreSQL` to `UTC`.
8. Execute the `SELECT NOW();` to verify that the default timezone server updated successfully.

You can also connect to the `PostgreSQL` from Cloud Shell and skip the part of the `VM Instance` creation.

Comment: I'm in Mountain Standard Timezone where we have DAYLIGHT SAVINGS.  I see 7 hours difference in the timestamp with timezone result from the "select NOW;".  So, it appears Postgres is honoring the 7 hour difference for non-daylight savings (whereas it is 6 hours during daylight savings).